# PagerTabStrip ignoring android:textcolor attribute

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat, pagertabstrip

I currently have a PagerTabStrip widget (from rev 21 of the support library) defined like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:textAppearance="@style/Theme.TTBase.PagerTabStripText"/>
```

With the textappearance style defined like this:

```
<style name="Theme.TTBase.PagerTabStripText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>>
    <item name="android:textColor">#7A378B</item>
</style>
```

The issue I'm currently experiencing is that the `android:textSize` and `android:textStyle` attributes of the style are applied to the `PagerTabStrip` as expected, but for some reason the `android:textColor` is being ignored and the text in the `pagerTabStrip` is black (the default color).

What could be causing the textColor to be ignored, and is there a fix available for this issue?

Comment: FWIW, there is no "AppCompat-v21" library. `PagerTabStrip` comes from `support-v4` and `support-v13`. It has no relationship to `appcompat-v7` (home of AppCompat). Try calling `setTextColor()` on your `PagerTabStrip` in Java code and see if you get a reaction. If you do, then something is up with the handling of the theme.

Comment: I meant to refer to revision 21 of the support-v4 library (I mistakenly refered to the latest revision of appcompat-v7, which is called [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)). Setting the textColor in code as you described works fine, so I'm wondering why the property in the theme isn't working (while other theme properties are applied)

Comment: Have you tried setting this up directly in the theme, instead of in `android:textAppearance`?

Comment: Adding the `android:textColor` property to the application/activity theme changes the text and line color of the `PagerTabStrip`, but this also changes the text color of the other components in the activity. (As expected, of course) However, I can't seem to find a way to just set the text and line color of the `PagerTabStrip`. Setting the `android:theme` or `app:theme` properties of the `PagerTabStrip` to a custom theme didn't work.

Comment: And of course I should have remembered that you set a style of a individual component with the `style` property, not the `android:theme` property. Using the `style` property worked fine.